# $q decorator with extra "success" method lost in promise chaining

Tags: angularjs, promise, decorator, extend

I've got a decorator for '$q' in my angularJS that add some extra methods to it, in this way:

```
  angular
  .module('myApi', [])
  .config(function ($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$q', function ($delegate) {
      var defer = $delegate.defer;
      $delegate.defer = function () {
        var deferred = defer();
        deferred.promise.success = function (fn) {
          deferred.promise.then(function(response) {
            fn(response.data, response.status, response.headers);
          });
          return deferred.promise;
        };
        return deferred;
      };
      return $delegate;
    });
  });
```

But the method disappears when I do this in the api:

```
var DataFactoryBase =  {

  get: function (url, headers) { 
    var dfr = $q.defer();
    dfr.resolve( api_bridge ({
      execute: function () {
        return $q.resolve($http.get(url, {headers: headers}));
      } 
    }));
    //this line still holds the decorator method
    var withSuccessMethod = dfr.promise;
    //this line returns a promise without the decorator methods
    var lostSuccessMethod = dfr.promise.then(handlerSuccessResponse, handlerErrorResponse);
    return lostSuccessMethod;
  }

}

function handlerSuccessResponse(response) {
  //do stuff
  return $q.resolve(response);
}    


function handlerErrorResponse(response) {
  //do stuff
  return $q.reject(response.data); 
}
```

How can I make **.then** also return a promise with the success method?

Answer (score 0):

Found out promise and defer are two different things (though the latter uses the former). Changing the promise returned when calling .then requires accesing the underlying promise in the defer. Can be done with `Object.getPrototypeOf()`

```
  angular
  .module('myApi', []).config(function ($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$q', function ($delegate) {
      var defer = $delegate.defer;
      $delegate.defer = function () {
        var deferred = defer();
        Object.getPrototypeOf(deferred.promise).success = function(callback) { 
          /* code */
        }
        return deferred;
      };
      return $delegate;
    });
  });
```